# Jenkins and NGINX Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, jenkins, networking, configuration

I'm trying to configure a NginX reverse proxy to Jenkins.

It's an AWS Light Sail machine.

Jenkins is running on port 7172 and I can access it using the public IP of the server.

I have already the NginX running in several sub.domains and working fine.

But for some reason, Jenkins is timing out under a reverse proxy. 
The following is my configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-available with link to /etc/nginx/sites-enable.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:7172;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
    }
  }
```

Not sure what else I can do.

Ubuntu 18LTS.
Jenkins 2.233
Nginx: nginx -v

In Jenkins I have configured as Jenkins URL the sub domain i want to use (jenkins.domain.com)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have anything written in nginx error log? Or it is not even hitting nginx?

Comment: no, nothing, I don't thing it's even hitting nginx, but it should

Comment: just changed the subdomain from jenkins.domain.com to jnks.domain.com and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Domain name jenkins.domain.com do not works, but changing to jnks.domain.com apperears to work.

Comment: seems like requests are redirecting to jenkins.domain.com online website. Just do nslookup jenkins.domain.com and check the ip it is resolveing to.